# Combine views sort criteria in exposed form

Tags: views

Drupal 7, views 3.6.

I have a view with 2 sort criteria: date and category. The sort is exposed in a form block.
Currently the user only has the choice to select 1 sort criteria, ie: sort by date or sort by category.

Is there a way to have the combination of these 2 criteria exposed, ie: sort by date asc, and by category desc ?

Thanks for your input,
Jerome

Answer (score 1):

Use [Better Exposed Filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module:

> The Better Exposed Filters module replaces the Views' default single-
>   or multi-select boxes with radio buttons or checkboxes, respectively.
>   Description fields and Select All/None links can be added to exposed
>   filters to make for a better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Use Grouped filters for combining 2 exposed criteria.

In views exposed form :

Select Filter Type to Grouped filters and then it will display Grouped filter form then u can select which filter u required between 2 exposed filters.